# asp.net membership hierarchy?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, roleprovider, formsauthentication

Hi i was just wondering how to implement a membership hierachy of sorts..

For example:

Headmaster

-- Teacher1

```
  -- student
  -- student
```

-- Teacher2

```
  -- student
  -- student
```

I was hoping to setup a scenario where a teacher can create students. Each teacher can ONLY see their students. The headmaster can see all teachers and their students.

I haven't been able to work out how I'd approach this using asp.net's memberships/roles?

any ideas would be most appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use roles to indicate which users are teachers and which are headmasters, so that teachers have rights to add students, but I wouldn't use the role provider for the teacher/student relationship. Instead, create a relationship in the database that connects students to teachers, and set up code in your the web page for viewing students so that if the current user is a teacher, only students tied to the current user are accessible.